# PHP is_dir not woking as intended

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a working ZF2 set up through the start up guide and decided to port it out to my new site. I've debugged all the way to an is_dir in init_autoloader.php and was wondering if anyone knows what could be wrong. Here's my code:

```
// Composer autoloading
$loader = include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$zf2Path = false;

if (is_dir('vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library')) {
    die('hello'); //This die does not execute
    $zf2Path = 'vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library';
} elseif (getenv('ZF2_PATH')) {      // Support for ZF2_PATH environment variable or git submodule
    die('hello1'); //This die does not execute either
    $zf2Path = getenv('ZF2_PATH');
} elseif (get_cfg_var('zf2_path')) { // Support for zf2_path directive value
    die('hello2'); //Nor this one
    $zf2Path = get_cfg_var('zf2_path');
}
```

So none of the die's execute but as mentioned above this code works fine on my local with exactly the same structure.

Comment: Are you sure the vendor folder has contents in production? Normally its contents are excluded from source control

Comment: Yes it does. I've also been replacing vendor/... path with other paths and the result is the same. Not quite sure what's going on.

Comment: can u give me out of var_dump(is_dir('vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library'))